# Why is a picture made from copying and pasting characters in notepad and converting corrupted?

Tags: python, image, file, encoding

This problem is essentially causing problems in coding a larger program. I have narrowed down the causes of the issues to this much smaller problem;

Simply put, we follow the following procedure;

1. Make a picture e.g. bitmap, using Paint
2. Convert this picture to a .txt file by renaming
3. Copy all the characters from the text file, accessed using Notepad
4. Paste this into a new .txt file
5. Convert this to the original picture file type e.g. bitmap

The picture we obtain for this will not open because it is apparently corrupted. Why is this happening?

When undertaking this I had assumed all the data was contained for the picture within the encoding, is this incorrect? Is there some "invisible signature" created to prevent creation of new picture files without appropriate software? If so, is there a different file type I could use which is supportable by pygame in Python 2.7.5?

Does the computer store files similar to how game installations store files relating to the installation and hence they don't allow the application to execute without being installed legally? If so is there a file type I could use which doesn't do this?

Overall mainly trying to figure out why this isn't working. Thanks for any replies and much appreciated

Comment: With converting the linefeed characters, will this send the same characters to the next file as I saw?

Comment: Reason trying to do this is because want to have a program reproduce a picture file without an actual copy of the file present, rather having the characters in a string. Trying to make an installer for a game I am making.

Comment: ok cheers for all the help guys

Answer (score 0):

Notepad is probably converting linefeed (0x0a) characters into DOS linefeeds (0x0d0a). Pretty nearly all Windows text editors will do this automatically.

This will, not surprisingly, ruin the image file. More generally, this is why you should never try to edit a binary file with a text editor.

Why on Earth would you want to do this, anyway? Why not just copy the file?

Comment: it is also not clear to me that all the valid pixel values are valid ascii.

Answer (score 0):

This gets down to the nature of image vs text encoding. Here's what happened, and then how to fix it:

1) Just as you expected, renaming the file to a .txt did nothing to the underlying data, which remained constant.

2) Opening it in Notepad did. Notepad will see a bunch of bytes (0-256) and try to interpret them as either ASCII or another encoding.

- Bytes between 32 and 128, as well as several below 32 will be interpreted as ASCII letters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, etc.).
- Most bytes below 32 and many above 128 will be interpreted as non-printing characters, and ignored or printed as their UTF descriptive symbol. That results in them being lost, or altered.
- Some bytes above 128 will be interpreted as valid multi-byte encoded characters, and displayed as such (E.g. UTF or another automatically misdetected encoding.)

3) Copying the characters copies these corrupted characters into the clipboard, and then back out to python.

4) Python will likely store the new string as a UTF string or a byte-string, either way, this conversion could create an additional set of cases like those in #2 if it doesn't match Notepad's misdetected encoding.

5) Converting back to binary bytes you get a different result, since the unerlying data has been mauled by 2-4.

Now, **how to fix it**:

Use a valid ASCII (or UTF-7) encoding algorithm. I suggest a base-64 one like the one used in MIME. Here's an example using Python's `base64` module:

```
import base64, binascii
# Here, we write the content of source.png to a text file store.txt
with open('source.png', 'rb') as src_file, open('store.txt', 'w') as store_file:
    store_file.write(binascii.b2a_base64(src_file.read()))
# Now, read the store.txt file and convert back to binary.
with open('store.txt', 'r') as store_file:
    data = binascii.a2b_base64(store_file.read())
# Finally, if desired, write out the recreated png file to make sure it worked.
with open('destination.png', 'wb') as dest_file:
    dest_file.write(data)
```

PS: For those wondering, this is the way that attachments in emails are sent, so if you've received an image in an email (and I'm sure you have) then your computer most likely received it encoded using a base-64 encoding like above. (There are some minor differences required to ensure MIME compatibility.)

Comment: Btw, cheers for this help. (was looking through stackoverflow stuff). A petty point to add is simply that one has to import binascii.